# E Newsletter sign up form

Tags: forms

I would like to create a sign up form for visitors to my site to receive an e newsletter. One of the stakeholders in the project has specified some additional functionality in that he wants an email to fire to the user after they have completed to form that asks them to validate their details and confirm they wish to receive the email prior to said details being stored on Drupal.

Is there an off the shelf solution anywhere in the community, or will I have to create something from scratch?

I have done a (very) quick search, which yielded no results - if someone has seen something/ heard of something that will give this functionality I would appreciate hearing about it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Simplenews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module

> Simplenews publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers.
>   Both anonymous and authenticated users can opt-in to different mailing
>   lists. HTML email can be sent by adding Mime Mail module.

[Read documentation](https://drupal.org/node/197057)